# How to block/allow a country in Nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress, nginx-ingress

Hello is it possible to block or allow certain countries in Nginx Ingress ([community](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)). It seems possible on Nginx installed on servers ([link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-by-geoip/))
But I want to apply similarly to this on Nginx Ingress.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this? The selected answer doesn't answer the question for me. It just enables the GeoIP support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is documented in the [user-guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-geoip2). You need to set `--use-geoip2 true` and `--maxmind-license-key KEY`.

Note that `geoip` is discontinued:

> Note: MaxMind legacy databases are discontinued and will not receive updates after 2019-01-02, cf. discontinuation notice. Consider use-geoip2 below.

Comment: And how can we block/allow a country? This answer just enables GeoIP support. The user guide doesn't mention how to whitelist or blacklist a country. I think this doesn't answer the question. I also cannot find any answer on the web.